# Logical argument applied to multiple cells in a row using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with 7 columns and lots of rows e.g.

```
structure(list(Suggested.Symbol = c("CCT4", "DHRS2", "PMS2", 
"FARSB", "RPL31", "ASNS"), p = c(0.0228515901406638, 0.0334943667503674, 
0.0380265628484489, 0.0479201571393373, 0.052163360517758, 0.0536304612182764
), p.10 = c(0.000166442958356447, 0.000401441243282832, 0.000537687151637518, 
0.000915758490675558, 0.00111333295283486, 0.00118675736050892
), p_onset = c(0.9378, 0.5983, 7.674e-10, 0.09781, 0.5495, 0.7841
), p_dc14 = c(0.3975, 0.3707, 6.117e-17, 0.2975, 0.4443, 0.7661
), p_tfc6 = c(0.2078, 0.896, 7.388e-19, 0.5896, 0.3043, 0.6696
), p_tms30 = c(0.5724, 0.3409, 4.594e-13, 0.2403, 0.1357, 0.3422
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to make a new column called 'summary' to give the value 'significant' when the value of "p_onset", "p_dc14", "p_tfc6" or "p_tms30" are <0.05.

How can I do this with dplyr?

Comment: "p_onset", "p_dc14", "p_tfc6" or "p_tms30" are <0.05.    do you mean all of them are less than 0.05 or any one of them is less than 0.05?

Comment: Hey, you said `p_onset`, `p_dc14`, `p_tfc6` "or" `p_tms30` are <0.05. It sounds like that when any one of them is less than 0.05, a 'significant' should be given. But you accept an answer that gives 'significant' when all of them are less than 0.05. Could you define your question well and explain more about what you want? This indeed confuses and mislead us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, which has meanwhile been improved, becoming more general, by @DarrenTsai's comment, to whom I thank:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = if_else(rowSums(across(p_onset:p_tms30) >= 0.05) > 0,
    NA_character_, "significant"))

#>   Suggested.Symbol          p         p.10   p_onset    p_dc14    p_tfc6
#> 1             CCT4 0.02285159 0.0001664430 9.378e-01 3.975e-01 2.078e-01
#> 2            DHRS2 0.03349437 0.0004014412 5.983e-01 3.707e-01 8.960e-01
#> 3             PMS2 0.03802656 0.0005376872 7.674e-10 6.117e-17 7.388e-19
#> 4            FARSB 0.04792016 0.0009157585 9.781e-02 2.975e-01 5.896e-01
#> 5            RPL31 0.05216336 0.0011133330 5.495e-01 4.443e-01 3.043e-01
#> 6             ASNS 0.05363046 0.0011867574 7.841e-01 7.661e-01 6.696e-01
#>     p_tms30         new
#> 1 5.724e-01        <NA>
#> 2 3.409e-01        <NA>
#> 3 4.594e-13 significant
#> 4 2.403e-01        <NA>
#> 5 1.357e-01        <NA>
#> 6 3.422e-01        <NA>
```

Comment: Good idea! But I think `if_else(rowSums(across(p_onset:p_tms30) >= 0.05) > 0, NA_character_, "significant")` could be better because you don't need to type the `4` mannually.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrenTsai, for having commented my solution! Indeed, your suggestion improves my solution: great idea!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `if_any()`(or `if_all`), where you can pass a `<tidy-select>` clause to identify multiple columns. It returns a logical vector so that you can further pass it into `ifelse()`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(summary = ifelse(if_any(starts_with("p_"), `<`, 0.05), 'significant', 'no'))

#   Suggested.Symbol          p         p.10   p_onset    p_dc14    p_tfc6   p_tms30     summary
# 1             CCT4 0.02285159 0.0001664430 9.378e-01 3.975e-01 2.078e-01 5.724e-01          no
# 2            DHRS2 0.03349437 0.0004014412 5.983e-01 3.707e-01 8.960e-01 3.409e-01          no
# 3             PMS2 0.03802656 0.0005376872 7.674e-10 6.117e-17 7.388e-19 4.594e-13 significant
# 4            FARSB 0.04792016 0.0009157585 9.781e-02 2.975e-01 5.896e-01 2.403e-01          no
# 5            RPL31 0.05216336 0.0011133330 5.495e-01 4.443e-01 3.043e-01 1.357e-01          no
# 6             ASNS 0.05363046 0.0011867574 7.841e-01 7.661e-01 6.696e-01 3.422e-01          no
```